# Can “an” and “année” be used interchangeably, is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

I have seen both *an* and *année* used almost interchangeably in both singular and plural. Are they really interchangeable? Does it depend on some dialects or something else?

Answer (score 18):

They are not really interchangeable — since in some situations one is nearly always used and the other isn't — but using one instead of the other will often be understandable, just non-idiomatic or losing a nuance.

As a rule of thumb,

- *an* is used for the unit of time;
- *année* is used for a period of one year, usually contiguous, often with a implied precise beginning (1<sup>st</sup> of January — *année civile* —, 1<sup>st</sup> of September — *année scolaire* —, date of birth, ...).
- using *année* tend to focuses on what happened during the time span while using *an* focuses on the duration.  For instance

  - *deux ans de travail de perdus* emphasises the lost time (which could have been used for something else)
  - *deux années de travail de perdues* emphasises the lost work (perhaps it has to be redone)

Comment: I would not rely too much on this though: *l'an un*, *l'an de grâce*, *l'an 2000*, *année-lumière*, etc.

Comment: Are "deux ans de travail de perdus" and "deux années de travail de perdues" equally usual?

Comment: How the fact that "plusieurs années" is the most usual expression (instead of "plusieurs ans") fits into this explanation?  I am unable to see how it focus "on what happened during the time span" instead of on the duration.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference.

*Année* is used to express a notion of duration which is not in "an" (unit of time):

> *J'ai travaillé cinq ans dans cette entreprise* (simply informative)
>
> *J'ai travaillé cinq années dans cette entreprise* (we want to underline the fact that it is a long time)

Comment: Unless preceded by "longues" which would carry the meaning you describe, "années" just sounds out-of-place in this sentence -- "ans" fits better.

Comment: I am unable to understand how "cinq ans" does not express a notion of duration

Answer (score 2):

I see another difference we may add to other answers.
When we talk about a period of time in the History, we use the term *années* :

*Cette technologie a été inventée dans les années 2000*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that soirée/matinée/année have to be about specific or special occasions or durations but they have some properties setting them aside from soir/matin/an:

1. they do not have to be contiguous:

   - +*J'ai passé deux années en Malaisie, 1991 et 2005*
   - ?*J'ai passé deux ans en Malaisie, 1991 et 2005*
2. they are compatible with internal quantification:

   - +*toute la soirée/matinée/année vs ?tout le soir/matin/an*
   - +*la soirée/matinée/année entière vs ?le soir/matin/an entier*
   - +*pendant la soirée/matinée/année vs ?pendant le soir/matin/an*
3. In general, *ans* seems to avoid indefinite plural contexts:

   - *?des ans, ?quelques ans* vs +*des années, quelques années*

And so it happens that we get :

- *un million d'années* and not ?*un million d'ans*

As French has this strange thing with *1 000 000* which must be constructed as an NP taking the counted noun as an indefinite complement the same way *un grand nombre* does:

- un grand nombre de chats
- un million de chats

This naturally excludes *ans* from this context while allowing it in:

- un million trois cent mille ans & un million trois cent mille années