# Étymologiquement, d'où vient la différence entre « an » et « année », « jour » et « journée », etc. ?

Tags: étymologie, latin, suffixes

Je connais les différences d'usage entre *X* vs *Xée*, où X = [*an*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6657/1995), *jour*, *matin*, *soir*.

Je désire connaître les conjectures, origines et les raisons qui expliqueraient pourquoi X et Xée diffèrent.

Le suffixe « -ée » les a-t-il causées ? La [page consacrée sur Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%A9e) n'expose pas ses effets dans cette situation.

Comment: Pur ressenti : j'ai toujours le sentiment que Xée est une valeur approximative alors que X est une unité plus ou moins précise (1 année = à peu près 1 an). Ceci m'est personnel cependant et je crois savoir que tout le monde ne partage pas cette opinion.

Comment: Une note étymologique ici en bas de page : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-%C3%A9e/0, mais rien de précis.

Answer (score 4):

Le radical indique le contenant, suffixé en "ée" il indique le contenu. Ce suffixe explique donc en partie les différences d'usage.

Cependant, il arrive souvent que contenant et contenu soient confondus par métonymie, et ce d'autant plus quand le contenant est abstrait, ce qui est le cas lorsqu'il s'agit de temps.

Un an, un jour, un matin et un soir désignent des subdivisions du temps qui passe alors qu'année, journée, matinée et soirée représentent les durées de ces subdivisions, la différence est ténue...

Le même phénomène peut se produire aussi avec des contenants concrets :

- Une « cuillère de soupe » au lieu d'une « cuillerée de soupe » .

L'usage a figé beaucoup d'expressions, ce qui limite les choix dans certains cas, mais pas d'autres.

- « Bonne année » mais pas « Bon an » (sauf dans « Bon an, mal an »).
- « Bonsoir » et « Bonne soirée »
- « Bonne nuit », « Bonne nuitée » est très rare.
- « Il a passé huit ans à l'étranger » et « Il a passé huit années à l'étranger »
- « Il a huit ans » mais pas « Il a huit années »

Comment: Comme l'a explicitement précisé son auteur, la question est à propos de l'étymologie, pas de l'usage (en ce qui concerne cela, voir par exemple: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/can-an-and-ann%c3%a9e-be-used-interchangeably-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il ne me semble pas que la question porte sur l'étymologie qui est de toute façon connue (participe passé -ata ayant donné -ade puis -ée, suffixe généralisé indiquant un contenu, plus précisément ici une durée). La question posée est « le suffixe -ée a-t-il causé les différences entre jour et journée, an et année, etc. ». La réponse est « Oui, ce suffixe induit une différence de sens qui explique en partie la différence d'usage ». Si ce n'est pas clair, je dois modifier ma réponse, si je suis à coté de la plaque, je l'effacerai ...