# "L'an dernier" or "l'année dernière"

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

"I went to Italy last year."

> Je suis allé en Italie ____.

Should "l'an dernier" or "l'année dernière" be used? I looked at this [forum question](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lan-dernier-prochain-lann%C3%A9e-derni%C3%A8re-prochaine.619622/?hl=fr), but there are so many answers that are different and even contradictory that I can't draw any conclusion from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While *an* and *année* are not always interchangeable (see [Can “an” and “année” be used interchangeably, is there a difference in meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/can-an-and-ann%C3%A9e-be-used-interchangeably-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning)), ***l'an dernier*** and ***l'année dernière*** both mean exactly "**last year**", i.e. in 2015 if we are in 2016.

At the end of the sentence, I would have only used the second form though as it sounds better to my ears, but perhaps is it just me.

> Je suis allé en Italie l'année dernière.

On the other hand, if the sentence is reversed, I would use equally:

> L'an dernier, je suis allé en Italie.

and

> L'année dernière, je suis allé en Italie.

Comment: I wonder if it's relevant that all your acceptable examples are iambic/trochaic. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Que mes examples soient d'une étrange métrique / est le fruit du hasard, et non d'un excentrique !*

Comment: @LukeSawczak ouch, il fallait bien sûr lire **exemples**...

Answer (score 4):

De [Questions de langue](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#10_strong-em-an-anne-em-strong) par L’Académie française :

> #### *An, année*
>
> *An* et *année* sont parfois substituables l’un à l’autre. Chacun de ces noms a cependant des emplois propres, ce qui s’explique notamment par leur formation : *année* est dérivé du nom *an* auquel le suffixe *-ée,* qui désigne le contenu (comme dans *cuillerée, bouchée, becquée*), a été ajouté (voir de la même façon les séries *soir-soirée, jour-journée, matin-matinée*).
>
> – *An* désigne une période indivisible, une simple unité de temps, abstraction faite des divisions que l’on pratique dans l’année. Ce mot s’accompagne rarement d’un adjectif qualificatif ; en revanche, c’est lui que l’on emploie le plus fréquemment avec un adjectif numéral pour exprimer la durée (*il y a dix ans* ; *dans, pendant, depuis vingt ans* ; *deux ans plus tard*), pour indiquer un âge (*elle a sept ans*) et situer un moment dans une époque (*l’an II de la République* ; *en l’an 2000*).
>
> – *Année*, qui est presque toujours qualifié par un adjectif ou une autre expansion du nom, est la période annuelle considérée dans la durée, avec les caractères propres qui la distinguent (*année julienne, grégorienne* ; *année civile, bissextile* ; *l’année dernière, prochaine*), ses divisions (*au début, à la fin de l’année* ; *il a travaillé les six premiers mois de l’année*), les évènements qui s’y passent (*l’année de son mariage* ; *c’était l’année du traité de Versailles*).
>
> Pour plus de détails sur l’emploi de ces mots, on consultera avec profit les articles *An* et *Année* de la neuvième édition du *Dictionnaire de l’Académie*.