# une fois par année/an - what's the difference?

Tags: sens, synonymes

I think I understand the general difference between *année* and *an*, but here's one example which got me confused because both seem just as likely.

---

"C'est un événement à ne pas manquer, car ça n'arrive qu'une fois par année."

"C'est un événement à ne pas manquer, car ça n'arrive qu'une fois par an."

Comment: They both can be used, but in everyday talks, it's `an` that is mostly used (if it can help)

Comment: @jlliagre: I don't think it would be wise to close such specific questions as duplicates of a generic question that can only be answered with guidelines and rules of thumbs that are usualy hard to interpret.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Indeed. Vote retracted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about *an* vs *année* are recurrent in FSE. See for example [Can “an” and “année” be used interchangeably, is there a difference in meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/can-an-and-ann%C3%A9e-be-used-interchangeably-is-there-a-difference-in-meanin)

In your specific case, the most common usage is the second one (*une fois par an*) but the first one shouldn't be ruled out.

If the year it is about is not a calendar year but some period of one year, like *une année scolaire* or *une année fiscale*, the first one would be equally possible.

If an adjective like *scolaire, fiscale, civile, calendaire, entière, complète...* is used, then *année* is mandatory; e.g.:

> "C'est un événement à ne pas manquer, car **il** n'arrive qu'une fois par **année scolaire**.

Comment: Thank you. Is it wrong to use "année" in "ils font, une fois par année, un défilé"?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be wrong, just less common than *ils font, une fois par an, un défilé*. Note also that most of the occurrences of *ils font, une fois par année* are from Québec so the expression might be more mainstream there.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *qu'une fois par an* is expected, as *an* is used as a unit of time. It's also possible to use *année*, denoting an individual period of time, but you'd have to phrase it *qu'une fois chaque année* (once each year).

Answer (score 1):

Both are [correct French](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+fois+par+ann%C3%A9e.%2Cune+fois+par+an.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20par%20ann%C3%A9e%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20par%20an%20.%3B%2Cc0); this can be asserted since both expressions are found before a full stop, as can be verified in the ngram. However, "une fois par an" is very common in written material, whereas the usage of "une fois par année", which is far from rare but yet far from being as  important, could be due to the greater freedom in the choice of words that is characteristic of writing, and therefore this  means that the frequency in the spoken language could be lower still. Nevertheless, both can be used in speaking. Personally, I wouldn't find "année" odd. I would find "une fois l'année" very unusual, even though it is [still correct](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+fois+l%27ann%C3%A9e.%2Cune+fois+l%27an.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20l%27%20an%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20l'%20ann%C3%A9e%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20l'%20an%20.%3B%2Cc0) and I wouldn't use this form, keeping to "une fois l'an". Notice from this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+fois+l%27an.%2Cune+fois+par+an.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20l%27%20an%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20par%20an%20.%3B%2Cc0) that "une fois par an" is much more common than "une fois l'an".